# OPENCV 2.4.9 use basler pylon4 connect to basler gige camera and ubuntu14.04

Tags: opencv

I'm trying use opencv connect to basler Aca2500-14gm GIGE Camera ,but I am working with Basler Pylon 4 and OPENCV version 2.4.9 and some problems,
make my c++ code have error.
My os ubuntu14.04

I would be very grateful if some one could help me please
Thanks.

here is error：
error: ‘HWND’ does not name a type HWND GetWindowHandle() const;

here is my code:

enter code here

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/PylonGUI.h>

using namespace Pylon;
using namespace std;
static const uint32_t c_countOfImagesToGrab = 100;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int exitCode = 0;
    pylon runtime system
    Pylon::PylonAutoInitTerm autoInitTerm;
    try
    {
        CInstantCamera camera( CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());

        cout << "Using device " << camera.GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;

        buffers
        camera.MaxNumBuffer = 5;
which
        camera.StartGrabbing( c_countOfImagesToGrab);

        CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;
RetrieveResult() method
        while ( camera.IsGrabbing())
        {
ms is used.
            camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

            if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
            {
                cout << "SizeX: " << ptrGrabResult->GetWidth() << endl;
                cout << "SizeY: " << ptrGrabResult->GetHeight() << endl;
                const uint8_t *pImageBuffer = (uint8_t *) ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();
                cout << "Gray value of first pixel: " << (uint32_t) pImageBuffer[0] << endl << endl;

#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
                Pylon::DisplayImage(1, ptrGrabResult);
#endif
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Error: " << ptrGrabResult->GetErrorCode() << " " << ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (GenICam::GenericException &e)
    {
        cerr << "An exception occurred." << endl
        << e.GetDescription() << endl;
        exitCode = 1;
    }
    cerr << endl << "Press Enter to exit." << endl;
    while( cin.get() != '\n');

    return exitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend you use Pleora's SDK over Basler's for GigeVision - it's more safe to other camera uses and designed and implemented better than the vendor specific SDKs and has seen significantly more usage.  It does require a license however to remove the watermark.   I have no association with Pleora.

The example you've posted looks incomplete but your error indicates the SDK thinks you are compiling in windows.  This has nothing to do with OpenCV and has everything to do with the PylonGUI.h include, try guarding it in an #ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD.

Comment: First,thanks your answer.I trying user basler pylon sample code on ubuntu14.04,but make sample code have the same error (‘HWND’ does not name a type HWND GetWindowHandle() const;)

Comment: as I mentioned, this is most likely macro defined related - like they are looking for __linux or __linux-_ or other variants and the gcc stack in Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't define the one they are looking for.  search for typedef x HWND (x could be int or handle for instance) in the SDK headers and work backwards.

Comment: Going to go with use Pleora's SDK again - to indicate how much basler tests their SDK on linux: I found that they don't provide any typedefs or handling of HWND in HWND CPylonImageWindow::GetWindowHandle. I searched for CPylonImageWindow in all of the included shared objects, which provided no references. So at either they don't support using PylonGUI.h on linux or the current version of the SDK out now is broken (wrt GUI) and they should be notified.